# Changing the size of status message in MS CRM Workflows

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

We are having some workflows crash due to a workflow status message being too large. The messages are set when we stop workflow with status cancelled and then we set the status message.

Is there a way to increase the size of this field?

Comment: If the sole purpose of what you are trying to do is to log more meaningful messages from your workflows, create a custom entity and write messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to create a plugin that takes in the message and limits it to 2000 adding ... on the end.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that can be customised. You are probably better off using a shorter message.